# Practical steps in sense restraint

Tags: personal-practice, eightfold-path, right-effort

Right Effort in the Noble 8 fold path has 4 components, the first being the prevention of the arising of unarisen unwholesome states. I've found in Bhikhu Bodhi's 'The noble eightfold path: Way to the end of suffering', a kind of general description of what is called 'sense restraint' as a tool one can use to prevent these states from arising. I find the book to be a great resource. However, I think that his description here does not give me enough detail to be able to implement it. Can someone suggest additional reading material that will give more detail and perhaps examples? Kind regards and much metta!